# Unexpected token var

Tags: javascript, var

```
//Called when application is started.
function OnStart()

// Set counter default to zero
var $counter = 0

// Display total
$counter.text(counter);

//Subtract
$("#fire").click(function(){
counter = counter - 1;
$counter.text(counter);
```

I'm trying to make a button that subtracts 1 from a counter I'm very new to js so sorry if it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function OnStart()` declares a function, but you cannot do this while omitting the `{}`. Instead of finding `{` the interpreter found the `var` keyword and let you know.

You should be using `OnStart()` (without using the function keyword before it), in order to call the function, or if you meant to define the function, ensure that the opening `{` and closing `}` are properly included.